# Words/Phrase to praise someone who is praised often

Tags: phrases

Just really need an opening that stands out and says I appreciate you and have been touched in a way that you haven't encounterd.. ? 
Want to message someone who receives praise from so many already for their work and i dont want it to be down played or underestimated ... want to convey that my appreciation and love for what they stand for is  lol idk help guys.

Answer (score 1):

Please allow me to add my song to the choir of praise you well deserve.

(Or maybe
..my flower to the boquet ... 
..my bird to the flock ...
..my dish to the feast ...

You get the idea.)

And then a line or two about the personal effects on yourself.

Answer (score -1):

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

> OVERPRAISE
>   : to praise (someone or something) to an excessive degree:
>
> - overpraising a mediocre film
> - He knows he is dealing with a complex personality, someone who has in the past been both overpraised and condemned to excess.

Comment: -1. This is **not** what the question is asking for. *Excessive* is a negative qualification. How does this express "I appreciate you"?